# A question on Cantor's proof of countability of algebraic numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

So the exercise 2.2 in Baby Rudin led me to Cantor's original proof of the countability of algebraic numbers. See [here](https://srjcstaff.santarosa.edu/%7Ejomartin/IrratFiles/Cantors1874Paper.pdf) for a translation in English of Cantor's paper.

The question I have is regarding the computation of the height function as defined by Cantor, for the equation:

> $$\begin{equation}a_0\omega^n+a_1\omega^{n-1}+\dots+a_n=0\tag{1}\end{equation}$$

where all coefficients are integers. Here is the relevant bit from Cantor:

> If we go back to equation (1), which an algebraic number $\omega$ satisfies and
> which, according to our restrictions, is completely determined, we can call the
> sum of the absolute values of the coefficients and the number $n-1$ (where $n$ is the degree of $\omega$) the *height* of the number $\omega$ and denote it with $N$; using the now common notation, we therefore have
> $$N=n-1+|a_0|+|a_1|+\dots+|a_n|.\tag{3}$$
> According to this, the height $N$ is for each real algebraic number a specified positive integer; conversely for each positive integer value of $N$ there are only a
> finite number of algebraic real numbers with height $N$; let the number of these be $\varphi(N)$; for example, $\varphi(1)=1$; $\varphi(2)=2$; $\varphi(3)=4.$

**Question:** But when I try to compute $\varphi(N)$, it doesn't match with Cantor's results! For example, consider $\varphi(2)$ - there are two possible cases, one for degree $n=1$ and other for degree $n=2$. For $n=1$ we have from (3), $$2=1-1+|a_0|+|a_1|\implies 2=|a_0|+|a_1|\implies|a_0|=|a_1|=1\quad\text{or}\quad |a_0|=2$$ which corresponds respectively to the equations $\omega\pm 1=0$ and $2\omega = 0$. Thus for $n=1$ alone we get $3$ such $\omega$.

Where is my mistake in computing $\varphi$?

Answer (score 4):

Note the requirement in the first sentence "the coefficients $a_0, a_1, \dots, a_n$ to have no common factor".

In the equation $2\omega = 0$, with $a_0 = 2$ and $a_1 = 0$, both $a_0$ and $a_1$ have $2$ as a common factor, so this equation is not allowed.  (Zero is divisible by every number.)

This makes sense because otherwise it would be ambiguous whether $\omega = 0$ has height 1 or 2.  There is supposed to be a unique equation "according to our restrictions" satisfied by each algebraic number, and so by these rules, the equation for $\omega=0$ is $\omega + 0 = 0$ ($a_0 = 1, a_1 = 0$) and not $2\omega + 0  = 0$.

Comment: I did some further computations; I found that Cantor's construction does not overcount the roots corresponding to every given height. So yeah, that makes sense as to how $\varphi$ leads to an ordering of the algebraic numbers. Thank you, it was quite an oversight on my part to see whether or not the roots are being counted exactly once.